# AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName inconsistent with HttpContext.Request.Cookies - why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, antiforgerytoken

We have an app written in ASP.NET MVC 3, that uses `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`.

We want to validate the token in our custom attribute (without a need of specifying the default attribute `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`). This should be pretty straightforward, but I've found an interesting inconsistency.

1. All the code below is running within the following method:

   ```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
   public class ValidateJsonAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
   {  
       public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
       {
       ...
   ```
2. `AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName` value is `__RequestVerificationToken`. That seems to make sense.
3. `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies` contains 1 cookie - but its name is `__RequestVerificationToken_Lw__`.

**Question:** aren't those two supposed to be the same so I can use following snippet to get the cookie?

```
var cookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default cookie name changed between MVC 3 and MVC 4.  In MVC 3, the default cookie name contains "Lw" and extra underscores near the end.  Can you confirm that the cookie is being generated by an MVC 4 application instead of an MVC 3 application?

Comment: I assume that it's the @Html.AntiForgeryToken() that generates the cookie - in that case I'm sure that it comes from System.Web.Mvc, Version 3.0.0.0 ([assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("3.0.20105.0")]
). AFAIR, that's exactly the version that's shipped with ASP.NET MVC 3 - corresponding library for MVC 4 is System.Web.Mvc, Version 4.0.0.0 ([assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("4.0.20710.0")]) and such version is not referenced within a project.

Comment: The reason I ask is that the AntiForgeryConfig API wasn't added until MVC 4, and the question made it seem like you were *generating* the token using MVC 3 but *consuming* it using MVC 4, e.g. there were two different applications in play.

Comment: Actually... You were right. There was an incosistency in referencing libraries: System.Web.Mvc from MVC3 and System.Web.WebPages from MVC4. It wasn't that easy to notice as WebPages has a different versioning pattern (1.0 -> 2.0, not 3.0 -> 4.0). Thanks a lot, that was a good suggestion.